# database is not configured. Available: ["default", "development", "test", "production"]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, database

when trying to connect to an additional 3rd party ms sql 2008 database I am getting the following error.

> 'npr' database is not configured. Available: ["default", "development", "test", "production"]

database.yml   -  the spacing is correct on the file,I added these below the production database.

```
npr:  
      adapter: sqlserver  
      host: *****  
      port: 1433  
      database: *****  
      username: *****  
      password: *****  
      encoding: utf8
```

I have added the following gems and I am able to read from this database.

> gem 'tiny_tds'
>   gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '4.1.2'

I am not sure if I missed something in making the application aware of this database configuration or not.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What is npr? What command are you using to launch your server? What happens if you do `RAILS_ENV=development rails s`?

Comment: npr is the additional database that i'm connecting to.

I was using this to connect in the model

class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
 establish_connection 'npr'

Answer (score -1):

You need to setup an environment for your 'npr' database. To do this add a `npr.rb` configuration file in `config/environments`. You can rename and modify and existing environment file such as 'development' or 'staging'.

Comment: I added this but was not successful in getting it to work.  I still get the same error